# How to implement multi-user interfaces in mean.io, can it be achieved by multiple local strategies of passport.js ?

Tags: mean.io

I am new to mean.io. I am building a web app with mean.io consisting of 6 different interfaces for 6 different users. I am confused how to achieve it in mean.io. Will building multiple local strategies in passport.js lead to the same result? If so then what about the menu provided by mean.io ? That would differ right?